# MS Access query to convert values from one currency to another currency

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Alright, I need a little assistance on a problem that I am facing.
I am working on a database project and have run into a problem regarding converting money values from a variety of different currencies into US Dollars.

The reason for my difficulty is that I need to maintain the original records in their original currency format but I also have to be able to convert these values to US Dollars, then perform a number of dynamic queries to sum up values of specific records and then output the final outcomes into a series of Reports.

I already have a table which contains all of my transactions (which includes currency type field, and several monetary value fields(12 fields per record))
I have a second table which contains the reference list of currency types along with the neccessary conversion rates over a 12 month period(so again 12 numeric fields) based on their relation to the US dollar. (ie. the entry of US dollar would be followed by 12 fields all containing a value of 1 for a 1-to-1 exchange rate)

I would like to be able to run a query which copies the records from my transactions table to a new table after converting them all to their US Dollar equivallent value. However I am not a expert in writing such a query and would like some assistance. is it possible to write a where clause into an expression within a query so that it takes each record from transactions, finds the correct conversion rate for the correct month, does the math and outputs to another table that same record with the modified values?

Or is there a way to perform this same function using a VBA script? If so what kind of recommendations would you make for that code?

**UPDATE OF PROGRESS/SOLUTION**
So after reviewing the solutions and comments here is the solution I came up with.
I built my exchange Rates table (ExRates) in the format that I had intended CurrencyName, Followed by the conversion rate for each of the 12 months (this is due to having to work with existing database elements)

Built the following 2 queries Match & Convert

```
    SELECT ForcastTrans.*, ExRates.JanRate, ExRates.FebRate, ExRates.MarRate, ExRates.AprRate, ExRates.MayRate, ExRates.JunRate, ExRates.JulRate, ExRates.AugRate, ExRates.SepRate, ExRates.OctRate, ExRates.NovRate, ExRates.DecRate
    FROM ForcastTrans, ExRates
    WHERE ForcastTrans.Currency=ExRates.CurrencyName;

    SELECT qryExRatematch.EntityID, qryExRatematch.Account, qryExRatematch.Currency, [qryExRatematch]![Month1]*[qryExRatematch]![JanRate] AS Jan, [qryExRatematch]![Month2]*[qryExRatematch]![FebRate] AS Feb, [qryExRatematch]![Month3]*[qryExRatematch]![MarRate] AS Mar, [qryExRatematch]![Month4]*[qryExRatematch]![AprRate] AS Apr, [qryExRatematch]![Month6]*[qryExRatematch]![JunRate] AS Jun, [qryExRatematch]![Month7]*[qryExRatematch]![JulRate] AS Jul, [qryExRatematch]![Month8]*[qryExRatematch]![AugRate] AS Aug, [qryExRatematch]![Month9]*[qryExRatematch]![SepRate] AS Sep, [qryExRatematch]![Month10]*[qryExRatematch]![OctRate] AS Oct, [qryExRatematch]![Month11]*[qryExRatematch]![NovRate] AS Nov, [qryExRatematch]![Month12]*[qryExRatematch]![DecRate] AS [Dec]
    FROM qryExRatematch
    ORDER BY qryExRatematch.EntityID, qryExRatematch.Account, qryExRatematch.Currency;
```

These got me the conversions that I needed and I can reconnect my reporting queries to these tables instead of the original ones I had done without the conversion.

Thank you everyone for your help, suggestions, and opinions and I credit Johnny Bones with this answer because his answer led me to the line of experimentation that help me reach my solution.

Thanks again for all your help

Comment: I hesitate to suggest a series of embedded [IIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/iif-function-HA001228853.aspx) statements. You should be able to accomplish this via a JOIN. You should probably have normalized your conversion table a bit more - putting each month on its own row to make joins easier.

Comment: I am trying to avoid over normalizing my data (had that issue already) I can potentially normalize the exchangerates into a seperate table. How would you recommend I structure such a table?

Comment: Third normal form is *not* **over**-normalization. Normal form was created to solve common problems, and decades of use have *proven* it exceptionally good at doing its job.

Comment: perhaps I am misunderstanding you then.
my original intent was to have the table set up so that each row was a specific type of currency with the months being the column headers. Are you recommending that I invert that so that the various column heads be the different currencies and the rows repersent a specific month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are your table layouts set in stone?  The easiest way to do this is to set up your currency table with 3 fields:

- CurrencyDate - The date of the new currency exchange rate
- CurrencyName - The name of the currency (Yen, Pound, Frank, etc...)
- CurrencyRate - The exchange rate on that day

Then you would set up a query called qryCurrentExchange where you would take the Max(CurrencyDate) for each currency.  This will give you one query that holds the current exchnage rate for each currency.

Create another query with your transaction table, and Inner Join the above query by the CurrencyName, and you should be able to pull in the exchange rate, which you would multiply by your currency field in your transaction table.  You can either leave the query as-is or turn it into a Make Table query if you want to output the results to a table.

Comment: I like your idea unfortunately I do not think it will work with the business requirements that I have to meet.
Right now the table has the following fields CurrencyName, Mth1Rate, Mth2Rate,... on to Mth12Rate
the reason for this is because it must hold and potentially reapply the conversion rate that was specified at that point in history. this table is also used as a lookup reference for several tables to create a dropdown for people to select the correct currency.

Comment: I could reasonably seperate the conversion rates out into a different table if needed to align towards your suggestion but how would you structure that query?

Comment: I gotta get back to something at my day job (Gotta hate putting out fires you didn't light...) but my table structure is scalable and logical.  I've been doing this stuff for years.  You can easily filter what you need, and apply that filter to any situation.  As it sits, it sounds like you need a new table every year?  That alone should tell you it's wrong.  I'll try to pop back later on and see if I can help with the query.

Comment: It makes a great deal of sense.

Comment: could you elaborate Remou? are you agreeing with Johnny Bones or with something I said?

Comment: As far as the conversion table structure goes, I am not rock hard set on doing it one specific way. I currently only have a reference table with a single field that just simply lists the available types of currency. so adding a table like what your describing should not be a problem.
just trying to figure out the query to get it to do the conversions to all of the records. (SQL is not my best language)

Comment: Johnny Bones; Can i get an example of how you would structure those queries cause im having trouble with it.

Comment: Are you storing anything but US Dollars in the currency table?

Comment: Yeah its pertty much every currency you can think of and plenty I never even knew of.